# How not to show image if there is none?

Tags: laravel

I have three table. Category, PostAd and PostImage.
To show post i have to show it from category table.
My controller Code.

```
$data['category'] = Category::with(['child','children','parent','postads.postimage','postads'=>function($q) use ($asc){
    $q->orderBy('created_at',$asc);
}])->where('id',$id)->get();
```

To display image i have to use nested relationship in postads.postimage.

Blade Code

```
@foreach($category as $cat)
    @foreach($cat->postads as $c)
        <a href="{{route('particular',['id'=>$c->id])}}">
            <li>
                @foreach($c->postimage as $pi)
                    <img src="{{asset('thumbnail/'.$pi->image)}}"  alt="No image" style="margin-top: 5px" >
                @endforeach
                <section class="list-left">
                    <h5 class="title">{{$c->adtitle}}</h5>
                    <span class="adprice">Rs. {{$c->price}}</span>
                    <p class="catpath">{{$cat->categoryname}} » {{$cat->categoryname}}</p>  
                </section>
                <section class="list-right">
                    @auth
                        <div class="like1">
                            <i class="fas fa-heart" pid="{{$c->id}}" uid="{{auth()->user()->id}}"></i>
                        </div>
                    @endauth
                    <span class="date">{{date('D',strtotime($c->created_at))}}-{{date('M',strtotime($c->created_at))}}-{{date('Y',strtotime($c->created_at))}}</span>
                    <span class="cityname">{{$c->address}}</span>
                </section>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </li> 
        </a> 
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

because of foreach loop my design gets damaged.
I want to show image alt but because of this nothing is shown and everything gets damaged.
[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can use `@forelse`

```
@forelse($c->postimage as $pi)
    <img src="{{asset('thumbnail/'.$pi->image)}}"  alt="No image" style="margin-top: 5px" >
@empty
    <!-- some HTML, default image or something, whatever you need -->
@endforelse
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#loops